# Quadratic bezier curve function in a path in SVG

Tags: svg, geometry, trigonometry

Looking for some help coming up with a function to create a quadratic bezier curve in a path. For example:

[image]

```
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M10 80 Q 52.5 10, 95 80 T 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

Any ideas on how to get the Q coordinates `52.5 10, 95 80` given the two points `M10 80` and `T 180 80`.

The curve would be based on the slope of the line. So horizontal line would have no curve but if it was 45 degrees it would be at its greatest curve.

UPDATE, a little more info, just trying to create a path that has a curve similar to yahoo pipes connecters:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unanswerable.  You haven't provided enough information.

It would be easy enough to calculate the X coordinates. But the Y values could be anything, it would depend on how much you want the path to curve.

Comment: Hmm, what if the curve was based on the slope of the path. For example, if the path was horizontal there would be no curve. However if at 45 degrees the curve would be at its largest.

Comment: If that i what you want, then update the question to add that requirement.  But specifying the initial angle just turns it into a simple trigonometry question.  You know the X coordinate (looks like it is exactly half way) and you know the angle. The Y coordinate is easily calculated given that info.

Comment: Hunt down your old high school math textbook (or use the internet). Hint: tan(angle) = opposite-Y / adjacent-X